# youtube-dl gracefully stop download

Tags: python, video-streaming, youtube-dl

I'm using youtube-dl to download a live stream and I'd like to be able to limit the time of the download, closing the connection once that time has elapsed. Is there a built in way to close the connection and save the file? I don't see anything in on the manpage but maybe I'm missing something. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hack-around solution: Use two terminal sessions, one for youtube-dl, and the other for sleep followed by sending SIGINT to youtube-dl.

Ex:

Terminal 1:

```
youtube-dl <url>
```

Terminal 2:

```
sleep 300; kill -SIGINT $(pgrep youtube-dl)
```

Specifically, SIGINT is the signal sent by ctrl+c, so this simulates ctrl+c'ing the youtube-dl process after the elapsed time.

Comment: Hint: `timeout` from `coreutils` can simplify this.

Comment: Mmmm even better.